# Does Bladebound Magus blade's masterwork bonus adds to Arcane Pool enchantment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

So I've recently come up with a concept for a Magus but a question I've encountered is that if a 5th level Magus uses his Arcane Pool to gain a +2 Enhancement Bonus, and the *Flaming Burst* property which costs a +2 bonus, does he still retains the +1 to hit from the weapon being a Masterwork? As it's stated that all Blackblades are Masterworks.

Comment: Could you clarify, it sounds like you're talking about having a *+2 flaming burst* (weapon), which is effectively a +4 weapon. I think you're wanting to turn your +2 into flaming burst instead. Notably, I think you're missing the line in Arcane Pool " If the weapon is not magical, at least a +1 enhancement bonus must be added before any other properties can be added."

Comment: Which, upon rereading the material, *also* doesn't matter because your [Black Blade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/bladebound/) is already a +2 (not masterwork) weapon. Or are you asking if you can change *that* +2 into *flaming burst*?

Comment: @AHappyTeddyBear, you may wish to complete registration (so that you get account logins) and may need to have your accounts [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This way you can edit you own posts without going through edit reviews and do things like voting, and accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Masterwork and enhancement bonus are not cumulative. All magic weapons are masterwork, and already include the +1 to hit. The difference between a masterwork and a +1 weapon is the bonus to damage from the enhancement.

So if a magus<sup>1</sup> were to do as you described, he would get a +2 Flaming Burst weapon, that has +2 to hit and +2 to damage.

<sub>1: of an higher level, as a 5th level magus couldn't do so, as pointed by other answers and comments</sub>

Comment: I think you misread OP (and I think OP misread the ability) but I believe they are talking about turning the +2 Enhancement (the max at 5th level Magus) into Flaming Burst *instead*. I think they're envisioning a *masterwork flaming burst (Black blade)*.

Comment: @Ifusaso Oooh, maybe. I tried to simplify the phrasing, but I might have misunderstood based on what I know of the ability. To be honest, I didn't go check the maximum enhancement at level 5 whenI answered, I should have. I'll wait for OP to clarify (or roll back the edit) and amend based on that.

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately, this doesn't work how you think it does.

In order to apply a special ability to any weapon (such as *Flaming Burst*) that weapon must *already* have a minimum of a +1 enhancement bonus. In other words, you can't have a *Masterwork Flaming Burst Weapon*, because first, it must be powered up to a *+1 Weapon*.

That being said, if this *were* possible, you would still retain the +1 to hit for the weapon being masterwork.